# typescript after adding any type not binding

Tags: javascript, typescript

Using normal JS, on TS I get complain about

```
const Item = ({ item, onPress }) => (
```

> Binding element 'item' implicitly has an 'any' type

So, by just putting any for type, it won't complain, but it won't work either...

```
  const Item = ({item}:{item:any}, {onPress}:{onPress:any})  => (
```

What is missing on the editing to make it TS accepted types?

Comment: const Item: any = ({ item, onPress }) =>

Comment: Did you try like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second line you are splitting it into two separate objects, just like if `Item` would be called with two arguments. I believe it's React props - it's a single object.

```
const Item = ({ item, onPress }: { item: any; onPress: any })  => (
```

**Note**: If it still complains, you will probably want to disable `no-implicit-any` rule in tsconfig.

**Note pt2**: Consider adding proper, sufficient types for both properties.

Comment: Or better yet: `const Item = ({ item, onPress }: { item: AppropriateTypeForItem; onPress: AppropriateTypeForOnPress; })  => (`

Comment: noImplicitAny is a Typescript rule (in your tsconfig) but it should not be a problem as the any are explicit here. There's this rule that might be a problem in tslint, though: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-any/